# Storing a collection of objects on an Arraylist

Tags: java

I am trying to store a collection of objects on the list `employ`. But I am getting an error on `employ.addAll()`, I have tried to `employ.add()` but I still get the error.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Employee {
public String FullName;
public float wage;
public int ID;
ArrayList<Employee> employ = new ArrayList<Employee>();

Employee(String name, float wage, int ID){
    this.FullName = name;
    this.wage = wage;
    this.ID = ID;
}

Employee e = new Employee("Tony", 1245, 2222);

employ.addAll(e); //here is where I a getting the error

}
```

Comment: Add a `main` method to your class, and put your last two lines of code within that. Then use `add` instead of `addAll`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`employ.addAll()` expects a collection, for adding single element use `employ.add()`.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Employee {
    public String FullName;
    public float wage;
    public int ID;

    Employee(String name, float wage, int ID){
        this.FullName = name;
        this.wage = wage;
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Employee> employ = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        Employee e = new Employee("Tony", 1245, 2222);
        employ.add(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: As I said in the question. employ.add() gives the same result.

Comment: And what is the result? Are you calling it within some method?

Comment: So it's not in any method. There are many ways to write a class/method, but the easiest in your case is to create a `main` method and put that code in it. I'll edit my answer with an example.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding a single `Employee`, so use `add`, not `addAll` :

```
Employee e = new Employee("Tony", 1245, 2222);
employ.add(e);
```

Beside that, `employ.add(e);` should be inside some method.